# How to design this case in OOM

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I want to do something like this:

What I have:

1. `A` (a generic class), possibly empty.
2. Specific implementation of class `A`: `A1`, `A2`, `A2`.

Now there is a driver program where I have a generic method as:

```
Class Driver()
 doSomething(A a)
    {
      a.setVal1();
      a.setVal2(); 
      .....
      etc.
    }
 main()
 {
   A a;
   if(user_input == "a1")
       a= new A1() 
       //Intention is, I should be able to access all the variables and methods of A1 & A(if any)
   else if(user_input == "a2")
       a= new A2()
       //Intention is, I should be able to access all the variables and methods of A2 & A(if any)
   doSomething(a);
 }
```

}

Now, here `a` can be `a= new A1` or `a= new A2` (decided at run time).

How can I implements this in Java?

Note: class `a1` (or `a2`) may have its own variables (and/or methods) & I don't want to put them in class `A`.

Any pointers/ help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the method `doSomething` to be agnostic of which implementation it is passed an instance of? If so, how could it make use of subclass-specific methods and fields?

Comment: You tag your question as `java` but don't have valid Java code in it. Please at least try to write valid code.

Comment: @Tichodroma: Hii.. I am sorry for that, I added the tag because I was looking for the implementation in JAVA language, I will definitely take care from next time. Thanks.

Comment: @TomAnderson: Thanks for your time. I was looking for something that  Nishant has mentioned.

Comment: @RajvidyaChandele: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when you declare the signature of a method as `doSomething(A a)`, you will be able to call **only** the methods defined in `A` or the ones from its **superclass** (if accessible) using the reference `a`.

It is possible, however, to explicitly *cast* `a` to an object of one of it's **subclasses** before invoking the methods specific to that subclass. Use of `instanceof` is *recommended* in such a scenario.

For example:

```
doSomething(A a) {
    if (a instanceof A1) {
        A1 a1 = (A1) a;
        a1.methodSpecificToA1();
    } else if (a instanceof A2) {
        A2 a2 = (A2) a;
        a2.methodSpecificToA2();
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, casting is a code smell. If there is a way to achieve your goals without doing this, using polymorphic calls to a shared interface instead, then that would be better. If there isn't, well, casting certainly works. If you tell us more about what goal you are trying to achieve, we might be able to find a better solution.

Comment: Hi Nishant, I need to verify (will take a lil more time) this, once I do that I will close it.